# How to define a function with a variable number of arguments?

Tags: emacs, elisp

Instead of this:

```
((lambda (a b) (apply '+ (list a b)))
 1 2)
```

it is possible to write this in Scheme:

```
((lambda args (apply '+ args))
 1 2)
```

Now it is possible to pass more than two arguments to the function.

When I try it in Emacs Lisp I get the error: invalid function.

How to define this function in Emacs Lisp?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Emacs Lisp, you can put `&rest` in the argument list of the function, to get the remaining arguments as a list:

```
(lambda (&rest args) (apply '+ args))
```